# Istio Programmable Routes at Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, kong

I was looking a lot about the capability for Istio to have programmable routes at the ingress controller as a solid replacement for Kong API Gateway plugins. A simple example would be to have a rule in the Istio Virtual Service that rejects API calls when the user has a license expired in the application that is behind.

That means, the Ingress Controller to be capable enough to query something inside the app to determine the license status, and based on that response, block/allow traffic that is coming from a particular customer (which are being identified by a header)

This is something I do with Kong plugins, but I didn´t find anything similar on Istio.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution to rejecting requests of a user is to attach that information in the authentication process (to the cookie or the jwt token), and then use Virtual Services to reject requests with those.

Another solution (more complex) would be to use Envoy Filters with Lua scripting, in which you can add custom logic and decide if you want to proceed with the request or not.